# Easy way to do port translation to bypass our own firewall

Tags: azure, web, port, firewall

so I have 0% experience with web programming, and the project I am working on doesn't have anything to do with it, but I hit a small roadblock and need to solve a small port problem.

So we want to build a cluster of GPU machines on Azure for some Deep Learning calculations, and want to install some applications on them and let our scientists use the app' GUIs to launch and monitor their jobs. The problem is that an app A for example runs on port 5050, but our firewall doesn't let us communicate to unusual ports. The problem is easy to fix from the Azure side, but our IT team won't let us modify our security policies.

That's why I need to find a hacky and fast solution to overcome this, I don't want to spend my whole internship doing something complicated for it, just something that does the job.

What I thought about was to have some kind of server running on the machines (let's say Machine A has public IP address ipbA and private IP ipvA) that when we type "http://ipba/app1" on our browser, the server on A will fetch the page "http://ipva:5050" (or "----://ipba/app2" -> "----://ipva:5051") and display it, but does this work if the page needs to be interactive because we would like to launch jobs?

I have no clue how to do this, if you could please just tell me what I should look into, google and read about, or if there is an easier way to handle it, (maybe some VPN stuff, which I don't prefer since we're moving towards a hybrid cloud architecture and I don't think we would want to VPN into all the different cloud platforms) that would be awesome :)

Comment: Try posting on ServerFault. This isn't a programming question. But really, you should be having a conversation with the local IT folks to set up proper firewall exceptions for outbound traffic.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think they would change their mind, we're just a single lab in the company, they won't change their policy just for us :/

Answer (score 0):

Two common solutions for your problem:

1. Set-up a reverse proxy on a standard port (such as 80 or 443 if you want some SSL certificates headaches).

All your domain names will point to the reverse proxy (single IP) but the reverse proxy will forward the traffic transparently to the real servers on their special ports.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension

For the technical details, in short: you keep in file(s) the configuration for each domain or subdomain and where they should be forwarded.

> **Chain of events:**
>
> - User types http://interface-1.company.com
> - Browser resolves interface-1.company.com (DNS: IP Reverse Proxy)
> - Browser connects on reverse proxy (port 80)
> - Reverse proxy reads configuration which says where to forward
> - Proxy forwards request to realserver.company.com:5050
> - Realserver relays response to reverse proxy
> - reverse proxy relays response to browser

I think that is what you are trying to achieve.

2. Set-up a VPN service which will be connectible through the proxy of your company and provide VPN clients to the end-users. OpenVPN clients can use an HTTPS proxy connection (your company proxy) to establish connexion to a remote VPN.

Once connected on the VPN, everyone uses the VPN's IP address + firewall policy, and are therefore no more restricted by the company's firewalling policy. Any kind of traffic can also be forwarded. This is harder to set up and your security team might not accept it. However, it's a fully functional solution and it can also offer additional security features if implemented properly.

I do not recommend going this way for all the paperwork that would involve.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help, I guess I'm going with the first solution :) Though I didn't quite understand what you added in your edit. http://interface-1.company.com means the URL i use to connect to the Linux VM running on Azure? or my company's website?

Comment: Here interface-1 is indeed the URL you want people to connect to (but it is in fact pointing to the reverse proxy). It is created by you. You must have new DNS entries for that solution to work.